# Wordpress get_var query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have created some custom tables within the WP database, and I'm referencing a table called 'projects' in this instance with this query.

'pr_no' is the Project Number

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$projectref = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT pr_no FROM $wpdb->projects WHERE ID=$current_user->ID");
echo "{$projectref}";
```

However, it echos nothing, and comes up blank. Where have I gone wrong?

At first I thought it was because I'd created my own table within WP, but apparently that's allowed. So I'm stuck!

--Update--

Fixed it for anyone who’s interested, you don’t need the $wdbp prefix on custom tables in a query. Amending the code to below fixes it.

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$projectref = $wpdb->get_var(“SELECT pr_no FROM projects WHERE ID=$current_user->ID”);
echo “{$projectref}”;
```

Comment: Another potential "gotcha" with your code is that you should enclose column names in back ticks like this: `ID`. Names like "ID" often tend to be reserved words in MySQL and the back ticks resolve that issue. (edited to add that back ticks don't show up in Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it for anyone who’s interested, you don’t need the $wdbp prefix on custom tables in a query. Amending the code to below fixes it.

```
<?php

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $projectref = $wpdb->get_var(“SELECT pr_no FROM projects WHERE ID=$current_user->ID”);
    echo “{$projectref}”;
```